# Item with position fixed act as position absolute

Tags: css

```css
.second{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.first{
    position:fixed ;
 top: 0;
}
```

```html
 

<div class="container">
    <div class="first">
        <li>fff</li>
     <li>fff</li>
     <li>ff</li>
     <li>fff</li></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

How to avoid the positioning of "second" over "first" container? I want to position both containers side by sie (first->left;second->right). With position fixed i want to apply the sticky property.

Comment: If you change the position to fixed the element is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used to position the element. And ever will be over other elements

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS `flex-box` to build what you want ;)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.first {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.second {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    <ul>
      <li>fff</li>
      <li>fff</li>
      <li>ff</li>
      <li>fff</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do with position: fixed but you can achieve your goal of side by side div using the following code.

```css
 .second{
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 border: 2px solid red;
        float:left
 }
.first{
    width:150px;
    height:150px; 
    border: 2px solid blue;
    top: 0;
    float:left
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="first">
     <li>fff</li>
     <li>fff</li>
     <li>ff</li>
     <li>fff</li></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of

```css
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from masoudmanson if you want the red box to align right, you can do the following;

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:no-wrap;
}

.first {
  flex-grow:1;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.second {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    <ul>
      <li>fff</li>
      <li>fff</li>
      <li>ff</li>
      <li>fff</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```